# Plotly graph having like different y axis for data

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, streamlit

this is my first post and so far I haven't found (as far as I have searched).
So I am trying to build a dashboard with streamlit and for the plots I am using plotly. I followed and example to have 'DateTime' as X axis and two different columns to make 2 lines using the same Y axis.

But my problem is that in the graph it appears that they have different Y axis and not the same. With the examples that I tried I don't get the same behavior and I tried different approaches to solve this but it remains the same. I am wondering if someone has the same error as me or has a solution.

I have tried using this data:

```
print(df)
```

```
DateTime   value_num1   value_num2

18:12:17     84.4937    84.49000

18:12:05     84.5038    84.47000

18:11:59     84.5247    84.49000

18:11:52     84.5386    84.52000

18:11:42      84.552    84.51000
```

```
df2 = df.sort_values(by="DateTime")
```

Ex1:

```
fig = px.line(df2, x='DateTime', y=['value_num1', 'value_num2'])
```

Ex2:

```
fig = px.line(df2, x='DateTime', y='value_num1')
fig.add_scatter(x=df2['DateTime'], y=df2['value_num2'])
```

I have also tried using melt:

```
dfm = df2.melt('DateTime', var_name='cols', value_name='vals')
```

```
DateTime         cols      vals

18:11:42  value_num1     84.552

18:11:52  value_num1    84.5386

18:11:59  value_num1    84.5247

18:12:05  value_num1    84.5038

18:12:17  value_num1    84.4937

18:11:42  value_num2   84.51000

18:11:52  value_num2   84.52000

18:11:59  value_num2   84.49000

18:12:05  value_num2   84.47000

18:12:17  value_num2   84.49000
```

```
fig = px.line(dfm, x='DateTime', y='vals', color='cols')
```

But have the same result. Can somebody please let me know what I am doing wrong or if there is another way to put a "normal" plot using streamlit? I tried matplotlib but it seems I couldn't use the image for streamlit.

This is how the plot looks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95oCz.png)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the time to datetime format.

#### Sample Code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px


data = {
    'DateTime': ['18:12:17', '18:12:05', '18:11:59', '18:11:52', '18:11:42'],
    'value_num1': [84.4937, 84.5038, 84.5247, 84.5386, 84.552],
    'value_num2': [84.49000, 84.47000, 84.49000, 84.52000, 84.51000]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert DateTime string to datetime format.
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'],format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.time

fig = px.line(df, x='DateTime', y=['value_num1', 'value_num2'])
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(autorange="reversed")
)
fig.show()
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Hi Ferdy,  I tried this but it seems it didn't work. So I saved the dataframe to a TSV file and load it to a df and it seems to work. The conversion of the date totally works but I suspect that something else in my code or the way I am handling it makes that error to appear. So I am gonna go with writing the file then reading it because that is what worked for me. 

Thank you a lot for your answer.